# CSS: how to place two div's into another

Tags: css

I really have struggle with placing two div's next to each other. If I use a float, the cover-div seems like it doesn't 'see' the div's that are inside of him. If I use a position, the div's do not want to get in one line. This is the best solution I have so for. But if I put more text in the main-div than in the side-div, or the other way around, they do not start at the same line anymore.

the html:

```
<div class="cover">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="inner">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="side">
        <div class="inner">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the css:

```
div.cover {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: none;}

div.main {
width: 65%;
height: 100%;
background: none;
display: inline-block;
top: 0px;
margin: 1%;}

div.side {
width: 25%;
height: 100%;
background: none;
display: inline-block;
top: 0px;
margin: 1%;}

div.inner {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 1%;
text-align: left;
margin-bottom: 1%}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Eva

Comment: Read this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: "inside of him", why are div's always guys!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fpdfww6p/

Comment: add vertical-align:top; to the side divs

Comment: or use `display:table` if you want the left and right columns to be equal height

Answer (score 2):

Just add `vertical-align:top` to your `div.main` div:

```css
div.cover {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: none;
}
div.main {
    width: 65%;
    height: 100%;
    background: none;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0px;
    margin: 1%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
div.side {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background: none;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0px;
    margin: 1%;
}
div.inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1%;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="inner">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="side">
        <div class="inner">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here created a quick fix for you.

Using clearfix + gave the backgrounds some colours so you can see it working

```css
.clearfix:before, 
.clearfix:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
div.main,
div.side {
    float: left;
    background: white !important;
}

div.cover {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: blue;}

div.main {
width: 65%;
height: 100%;
background: none;
display: inline-block;
top: 0px;
margin: 1%;}

div.side {
width: 25%;
height: 100%;
background: none;
display: inline-block;
top: 0px;
margin: 1%;}

div.inner {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 1%;
text-align: left;
margin-bottom: 1%}
```

```html
<div class="cover clearfix">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="inner">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="side">
        <div class="inner">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cleaned a bit the code:

```css
div#divs{
    width: 100%;
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

div#divs div{
     border: 1px solid #000;
     padding: 1em .5em 1em .5em;
     margin-right: .5em;
}

div#divs div:first-child{
    flex: 2 0 0;
}

div#divs div:last-child{
    flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="divs">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</div>
    
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. 
    </div>
</div>
```

## [JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gdyLmtrv/)

### What?

I just used some properties of flexbox. I recommend to you read about this.

- [The Ultimate Flexbox Cheat Sheet](http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html)
- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Hope this helped.